# what is the equivalent concept in apache royale for flexmdi.swc , flexlib.swc

Tags: apache-flex, apache-royale

When I am migrating the flex to royale application , i am unable to implement the concept MDIWindow Concept in royale.
I am able to find in Visual Studio Code IDE the implementation

```
//Generated from: C:\RemoteObjectAMFTest\external\flexlib.swc
package flexlib.mdi.containers

public class MDIWindow extends mx.containers.Panel
```

but not able to find at compile time.
could you please help to compile MDIWindow  successfully in royale?

> col: 9 Warning: Definition flexlib.containers.MDIWindow could not be found.
>   import flexmdi.containers.MDIWindow; or flexlib.containers.MDIWindow

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, MDIWindow has not been ported to Royale. Your best bet might be to decide on the features you actually need for your app and implement those parts yourself. Hope this helps.